# How to deal with Tim

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, story, knowledge, number-sequence

My friend Tim is a real dick. Whatever happens to him he just won't die! I asked him what the secret to his power was (So I could kick his ass). He handed me a crumpled up piece of this paper with some numbers on it, gave me a wedgie and walked off.

The numbers are:

> 1 , 10 , 6 , 3 , 15
>   1 , 4 , 5 , 1 , 3
>   3 , 1.5 , 0.5 , 7.5 , 5

What can I do (If anything) to beat him?

Hint 1:

> These are 3 individual sets of numbers that may not be in order

Hint 2:

> Each sequence gives a different part of the answer

Hint 3:

> Two of the sequences are similar

Hint 4:

> An optional sequence to also consider is 2, 0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5

Comment: I have already bookmarked this question. If someone answer to this question, will I get a notification?

Comment: If you got one now, than yes :)

Comment: @BálintBudavölgyi Unfortunately no :-( I just came to site to check. No notification...

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson tagging a '@username' like this as the first part of a comment will notify that user. Also, some partial answers have been provided.

Comment: Anything to do with rot13(uggc://jjj.qvtvgnyfcl.pbz/zbivrf/uneel-cbggre/arjf/n841654/frperg-vafcvengvba-uneel-cbggre-qrnguyl-unyybjf-flzoby/)?

Comment: Possibly, but you'll have to explain it :)

Comment: You have changed one 1.5 into 7.5 in last line. Why is that? Orginal question was wrong or ....

Comment: Original question had a typo, very embarrassing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Going off @Bálint Budavölgyi's comment, I think the answer might be:

> The Deathly Hallows, from Harry Potter

My reasoning is:

> As Hint 1 says, the numbers in each list are not in order, so we must reorder them first.
>  The first line can be reordered as 1, 3, 6, 10, 15...; this has already been solved and verified as the start of the sequence of **triangular** numbers.
>  The second line can be reordered as 3, 1, 4, 1, 5...; this has already been solved and verified as the first digits of pi, the **circle** constant.
>  The third line (now updated) can be reordered as 0.5, 1.5, 3, 5, 7.5...; this sequence is the same as the first, but **halved**. (1/2, 3/2, 6/2, 10/2, 15/2...) This is why Hint 3 suggests that two of the sequences are similar.
>  Hint 4 suggests that the third sequence could also be 2, 0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5. This can be reordered as 1.5, 0.5, 2, 0.5, 2.5...;, which is the same as the second sequence but **halved**.

These sequences clue towards:

> the triangle, the circle, and then dividing one or both of those shapes in half.
>  Combining and overlapping these images gives the symbol for the [Deathly Hallows](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Deathly_Hallows), a collection of powerful artifacts in the Harry Potter universe said to have been created by Death.
>  *"According to legend, he who possesses these three artefacts would become the Master of Death,"* which would explain why we can't kill Tim.
>  (In reference to Hint 2, the three aspects of the image each represent one of the artefacts. Specifically, the triangle represents the Cloak of Invisibility; the circle represents the Resurrection Stone; and the line that divides the image in half represents the Elder Wand.)
>  [image]

Comment: Seems like a good answer, but I would expect a "trivia" tag if this were the case. You also needed to modify one of the sequences.

Comment: Ahh I totally missed that 7.5 apologies. You've got the symbol right, can you elaborate on the other hints/parts of the riddle

Comment: Updated my answer to elaborate on the hints.

Answer (score 5):

the first line is:

> Triangular Number Sequence -> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, ... (https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/triangular-numbers.html)

Comment: Yep you've solved this line

Answer (score 3):

The second line is

> 9, because the numbers can be rearranged to get $3, 1, 4, 1, 5, \_$, which are the first digits of $\pi$.

Comment: Yep you've solved that line. The answer is pi though not 9

Comment: Why did you say 9?

Comment: Its the next number in pi : 3.14159

Comment: Got me thinking the answer could be something like 'happiness', but I can't really see a link between first sequence and 'hap', or the last sequence and 'ness'.. We may however be looking for letters rather then nummers.

Comment: @TimCouwelier It could also shapes.  The first line is triangles, the second line is the circle constant.

Answer (score 1):

(Partial answer)

The first line could be:

> $21$, because
>
>  If you sort the numbers ascending, you get $1, 3, 6, 10, 15$.
>  Then if you subsctract the previous number from the actual, add it to the actual, and then add +1 you get the next number.
>
>   $x_n = x_{n-1} + (x_{n-1} - x_{n-2}) + 1$
>
>   $15 + (15 - 10) + 1 = 21$

It is definitely a stretch, but the second line could be:

> $8$, as
>
>  You sort the numbers ascending again
>
>  $1, 1, 3, 4, 5$
>
>  $x_n = x_{n-1} + x_{n-3}$
>
>  $5 + 3 = 8$

And I have a feeling that

> If you add up the answers of the three individual rows, you will get: [42](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/history/42-the-answer-to-life-the-universe-and-everything-2205734.html)

Comment: Am I on the right path?

Comment: Not for 42, having the first line being ascending is correct though